# jquery code: if clicked option from multiselect is already selected

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I'm looking for a jQuery code snippet that matches this condition:

*If the option of a multi select I just clicked is already selected, then...*

Thank you.

Comment: You really need to add some more detail here. Could you post a code snippet?

Comment: ...then ***what***, exactly..? Also edit your question and add your code there, where it should be legible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this HTML:

```
​<select multiple="multiple">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
</select>
```

You could use this script:

```
​$("option").on("mousedown", function(){
    if($(this).prop("selected"))
        alert($(this).val() + " is already selected");
});​​​
```

​

Comment: it's really good habit to enclose conditions inside `{}`

Comment: Yep it is.  It's also a good habit to capitalize the first letter of a sentence.

Comment: my sentence will not ruin precious life-hours of debugging.

Comment: @JasonWhitted Thank you, your code worked! :D